# Ground Reference for multi layer board

Tags: pcb-design, ground, emc, voltage-reference

I am currently designing a multi-layered PC board and there is situation where signals are referencing the ground plane meant to be used for the 3.3v supply. So, for example. I have a 3.3v plane on L8 with its ground reference on L7, however, there are some 5V signals on L6 which are now referencing the L7 gnd plane. Could anyone please let me know if this could cause any potential failures or EMI issues?

Comment: That really depends on your circuit and whether some of the components involved are sensitive enough to be disturbed by the currents of other component flowing in their ground plane. Usually more of a concern if it's analog.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the 5V signals are control lines for relays.

Comment: No issues. Don't even need a ground plane for those.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You might prefer to have high speed signal between 2 planes . Decoupling caps ought to be distributed  to become 0 V for AC high f. With many microvias as necessary. But don’t share noisy ground paths with analog

Comment: Avoid running high currents across the pcb. Consider the inductance of the 0V track if running mosfets to switch the relays. I had an instance where the mosfet was oscillating due to the inductance between the mosfet source and the 0V of the microcontroller driving the mosfet.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your layer stack-up.

Currents always get the fastest R and L path to go back to the GND pole of the connector of your board.

Let's call HOME that pole.

---

To answer your question:

If you route a fast switching GND signal to follow a longer path to go HOME than you increase emitted RF radiations.

Parasitic inductance of wires and planes in your board are antennas. Maybe they are inefficient antennas, but still antennas.

---

To confine RF radiations inside the inner layers, just remember to add stiching GND vias around the perimeter of the board.

At CISCO they use a step of 2.5 mm.

Vias' drill minimum diameter 0.3 mm.

They will create a sort of a Faraday's cage for RF radiations.